# Setup .Netcore app with Nginx fails - getting 502 bad request

Tags: nginx, .net-core, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a .Netcore app which runs through a container. I need to host this container with Nginx as a reverse proxy. So I have an nginx container configured to act as a reverse proxy that forwards traffic to my .netcore app container. The problem is that I keep getting ***502 bad request*** while checking my app with curl. when I check the nginx container logs, I get something like this:

```
2020/05/10 11:35:51 [error] 6#6: *2 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.18.0.1, server: vs.local, request: "GET /vs.local HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/vs.local", host: "vs.local"
```

I've read many articles and solutions but unfortunately no luck.

P.S: My *default.conf* and *Dockerfile* for .netcore app are like below:

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["TestAppForKubernetes/TestAppForKubernetes.csproj", "TestAppForKubernetes/"]
RUN dotnet restore "TestAppForKubernetes/TestAppForKubernetes.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/TestAppForKubernetes"
RUN dotnet build "TestAppForKubernetes.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:80

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "TestAppForKubernetes.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TestAppForKubernetes.dll"]
```

**Nginx default.conf:**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name vs.local;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;
}
    location /vs.local {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Would you please give me a hand here? I'm stucked!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer.
The trick is that you have to define your docker gw in the reverse proxy config.
So instead of:

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
```

the proxy_pass will be in my case:

```
proxy_pass http://172.18.0.1:5000;
```

Of course one other change would be to change the port, if the dotnet app is not listening on 5000.

Good Luck